# React Native and Android Studio: App Failed to build. Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

Tags: java, android, react-native, build.gradle

Hello I am new to React Native. I am trying to use an Android Emulator to run my Android App with React Native in Windows OS. I followed the instructions here https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup but I am getting these errors:

```
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 967 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info JS server already running.
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
info Launching emulator...
info Successfully launched emulator.
info Installing the app...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
```

This is my gradle properties:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip
```

My Java JDK version is 15.0.2

I tried changing the gradle properties to an earlier version but it doesn't let me since the minimum is 6.5version.

Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 0):

cmd:

cd ProjectFolder && cd android && ./gradlew clean

if not sucess try start as npx react-native start --reset-cache

if using expo: expo start r -c